# Java library that allow image bilinear transformation

Tags: java, image, jai

The case is that I have an image and I need to transform it with a bilinear functions:

```
x' = a10 + a11 * x + a12 * y + a13 * x * y
y' = a20 + a21 * x + a22 * y + a23 * x * y
```

As "transform" I understand getting new image that each sourcePixel(x,y) will be targetPixel(x', y') on targetImg. What's more I have all parameters counted (a10, a11, a12, a13, a20, a21, a22 and a23). Now I need some library in Java language to perform this transformation. The exmaple of tranformation shows picture below.

[image]

I do some research and I found JAI give some tools, but all examples I found shows that Bilinear Interpolation is use to Antialiasing rotated images.

The question is, do JAI allow such transformation and if not, do you know other library that could help?

Answer (score 1):

you can use java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp or knowing that bilinear transformation is an extension of linear transformation see multigraph.LinearInterpolator from [multigraph project](http://multigraph.sourceforge.net).

Comment: I don't get it. How to use java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp to make bilinear transformation? That's true that there is AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR, but constructor for this class looks like this: public AffineTransformOp(AffineTransform xform, int interpolationType), and as far as I understend it, method transform will make a transformation, but still it will make an Affine transformation (with bilinear antialiasing method) - not bilinear transformation itself ?

Comment: As for multigraph.LinearInterpolator, this class is Util class for transforming (which actually is not a problem, cause as I write all parameters are counted). I didn't fount any hint how to use it for image transformation operation. I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

it is so easy by using Opencv Library

Comment: To use such a mighty **native library** for such a simple operation sounds like overkill for me.

Comment: you alright , but opencv is "other" library can be help "http://code.google.com/p/javacv/"

Answer (score 0):

JavaCV looks like something I looking for but there is horrible lack of documentation. I write something like this but it's not working well (i get all black targetImage).

```
static float[] confX = new float[] { a10, a11, a12, a13 };
static float[] confY = new float[] { a20, a21, a22, a23 };

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/in.tif"));
  IplImage in = IplImage.createFrom(sourceImage);
  CvMat m = CvMat.create(3, 3);

  cvGetPerspectiveTransform(confX, confY, m);
  cvWarpPerspective(in, in, m);
  cvSaveImage("C:/out.tif", in);
}
```

Someone have an idea what's wrong with it ?